# is there generic method to get the network error string out of the enum NetworkError or do i need to build one?

Tags: c++, qt, networking, error-handling

I have basic function that prints network errors based on enum NetworkError.
that looks like this :

```
void HttpClient::HandleNetworkError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError& networkError)
{
  switch(networkError)
  {
  case(QNetworkReply::ConnectionRefusedError):
   LOG_MSG("NO NETWORK CONNECTION ConnectionRefusedError!! ");
   break;
  case(QNetworkReply::HostNotFoundError):
   //handle the html output is no internet connection is found
   LOG_MSG("NO NETWORK CONNECTION HostNotFoundError!! ");
   break;
  case(QNetworkReply::SslHandshakeFailedError):
   //handle the html output is no internet connection is found
   LOG_MSG("CONNECTION SslHandshakeFailedError!! ");
   break;
  case(QNetworkReply::UnknownContentError):
   LOG_MSG("CONNECTION UnknownContentError!! ");
   break;
  default :
   LOG_MSG("CONNECTION not defined default error UnknownContentError!! ");
  }

}
```

now i need to support more errors , in fact all the error that list in enum NetworkError, so does it means i need to
added them all to this switch case ? or there is some kind of generic Qt functions that do this translation ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is already answered in the [`QNetworkReply::error()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#error-1) signal documentation:

> Call [`errorString()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#errorString) to obtain a textual representation of the error condition.